# How can I choose rows and columns if the index/header contains certain integer in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, header

I have an input/output data where index and header have numbers that represents different types of industries. I want to create new columns and rows that would represent the sum of columns and rows that belong to certain industry group. To give an example(please refer to the example that I manually made as below), I would want to create new row/column that would have index/header as US_industry_135/CAN_industry_135  which would sum the rows/columns that has industry number 1, 3, or 5. The below example is a small set that I manually created, but I wanted to know if there is a way to put the condition in summation so that I sum rows/columns whose index/header has numbers that belong to specific numbers. I could extract the numbers from header/index and create make a separate row/column, but I was wondering if there is a way to directly check from the index/headers without creating new columns. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'US1':[3, 2, 1, 4,3,2,1,4,2,3,7,9],'US2':[8,4,9,2,1,3,4,2,5,6,18,11],'US3':[2,4,2,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,6],
    'US4':[7,4,8,2,2,3,2,4,6,8,17,15],'US5':[2,4,3,2,2,4,1,3,2,4,7,11],
   'CAN1':[3, 2, 1, 4,6,2,3,1,4,2,10,5],'CAN2':[8,4,9,2,5,7,3,5,7,1,22,13],'CAN3':[2,4,2,2,4,5,2,3,3,2,8,10],
    'CAN4':[7,4,8,2,2,3,1,3,2,4,17,10],'CAN5':[2,4,3,2,6,7,5,4,0,9,11,20],
   'US_IND_135':[7,10,6,8,8,8,6,9,7,9,21,26],'CAN_IND_135':[7,10,6,8,16,14,10,8,7,13,29,35]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['US1','US2','US3','US4','US5','CAN1','CAN2','CAN3','CAN4','CAN5','US_IND_135','CAN_IND_135'])
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define list of indexes of interest:

```
idx = [1, 3, 5]
```

Do the summation using specified columns:

```
df[['US' + str(i) for i in idx]].sum(axis = 1)
```

Alternatively, if you want to join summation column to dataframe, you can assign result to the variable:

```
s1 = df[['US' + str(i) for i in idx]].sum(axis = 1)
s1.name = 'NEW_US_IND_' + ''.join("{0}".format(i) for i in idx)
```

And add new column:

```
df.join(s1)
```